A clarification on interval censoring in modeling survival
Until reading Lecture 11: Interval censored and discrete-time data (2012) by Vinh Nguyen, I thought that the discrete time survival model would be the right statistical method for our study. My understanding was that discrete time survival analysis (Cox) includes interval censor. However, it seems that interval censoring is a separate technique (please correct me if I am wrong). Now, I am a bit confused about whether the interval censoring method or discrete time survival would be the right choice for my study.
In our study, subjects visit a center every three months (up to 18 months) to check the status of their disease at the following times: T0, T3, T6, T9, T12, T15, and T18. The main covariate, Test Status, is binary and time-dependent (1 vs. 0). The event is a binary outcome (1: Decline in health, 0: Stability in health). The study is a single-event. The data could look something like this:
ID  TIME   AGE  EVENT   TEST STATUS
1   0      45   0        0
1   3      45   1        1
2   0      46   0        0
2   3      46   0        1
2   6      46   0        0
2   9      46   1        1
3   0      34   0        0
3   3      34   0        0
3   6      34   0        1
3   9      34   0        1
3   12     34   0        0
3   15     34   0        1
3   18     34   1        0


Interval censoring means that you only know lower and upper limits for a time interval containing the event time, not the event time itself. In general, the time intervals might be completely different among the individuals in a study. That's called "random interval censoring" in the lecture that you linked. That general case leads to complications that need to be handled by special techniques, like those in the R icenReg package.
In your data, however, all individuals have the same time intervals: T0 to T3, T3 to T6, etc. That's a very simple form of interval censoring, called "fixed interval censoring" in the lecture that you linked. That is nicely handled by discrete-time survival models based on binomial regression (on properly formatted data). If you use a complementary log-log link in your binomial regression, you have what's called a "grouped proportional hazards model." This page goes into a bit more detail.
In your scenario, you certainly can proceed with a discrete-time model.

thank you so much for your time and help. As always, your advice is very helpful.
